# Using natbib and plainnat - no year appears to some references and also et al. not in Italics

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I use `natbib` and `plainnat` for bibliography, I use `\citep`.

1. The reference appears with et al. that is not italics – how do I change that?
2. Some references just appear with no year. How to fix that?
3. When same author and not same year, how do I get rid from the a,b notation of the same author? I tried `garynat` instead of `plainnat` and it solved the italics of et al. but 
   still problem with the missing year.

Answer (score 5):

*How to typeset "et al." in italics:* Copy the file `plainnat.bst` (located in the `\bibtex\bst\natbib` subdirectory of your TeX distribution) into your working directory and rename it to, say, `myplainnat.bst`. (Later, this file should be placed in your local TEXMF tree). In the renamed copy, search for the string `" et~al." *` (there should be four instances) and replace every instance with `" \emph{et~al.}" *`. In your `.tex` file, use `\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}`.

Your other questions can't be answered without a minimal working example.

Comment: It would appear that you need to run `texhash` from the command line after creating the new file (based on my Windows XP, MikTeX 2.9 experience)