# How to make citet author italic

Tags: citing, natbib, ieeetran

I'm using natbib and IEEEtranN.bst (or IEEEtran.bst)

```
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN.bst}
```

I want to make the author name and et al. both italic without making the number italic with \citet{}. For example, I'd like

*Kim et al.* [8] propose the use of ...

I tried using [lockstep's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15730/using-natbib-and-plainnat-no-year-appears-to-some-references-and-also-et-al-n/23278#23278) to change the IEEEtranN.bst file without success, by changing

```
FUNCTION {bbl.etal}{ "et~al." }
```

to

```
FUNCTION {bbl.etal}{ "\emph{et~al.}" }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all `\citeauthor` commands to print the names in italics, patch `\citeauthor` to do `\em`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{kim,
  author={Kim, W. and Tim, X. and Vim, Y. and Zim, Z.},
  title={Three letter names},
  journal={Im},
  year=2015,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\citeauthor}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\em}{}{}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN.bst}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{kim} \cite{kim} propose the use of three letter names.

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]