# et al. citation emphasized in Lyx

Tags: lyx

My university has decided that "et al." should be emphasized. 
In order to do so, I have followed Citations are collected in Mendeley 1.17.13 which has BibTex syncing enabled. The citation is inserted into Lyx 2.2.3. with citation style natbib author-year, bibliography style plain, bibliography generator default.

This question has been asked several times, e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15730/using-natbib-and-plainnat-no-year-appears-to-some-references-and-also-et-al-n). I have replaced "et al." in the agsm.bst style, replaced it with \emph{et~al.} and saved under a different name (agsm_hh.bst). There were 4 instances. I have reconfigured and restarted Lyx, and set the BibTex Generated Bibliography style set to agsm_hh.

This gives an error: [image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Where did you put your modified `.bst` file?  Does it work if it's in the same folder as your document?

Comment: Yes! It needed to go into the same folder as the document.

Comment: Ok. I think we can close this as a duplicate. If you want to use the modified style with other documents you can put it in your home `texmf` folder. See the linked question and also this one: [How to have local package override default package](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/8357)